# adb reboot vs adb shell reboot

Tags: adb, linux

I run the commands from my laptop. But, I can't understand what is the difference. It looks like both commands just restart the mobile device.

What is the difference between `adb reboot` and `adb shell reboot`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference. Ultimately both set `sys.powerctl` property to `reboot,<reason>` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/reboot/reboot.c#67), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/adb/daemon/reboot_service.cpp#74))</sup>. `init` then handles the property to proceed a proper shutdown or reboot <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r1/init/init.cpp#771))</sup>. `reason` string optionally describes why the device was rebooted (see `persist.sys.boot.reason` property after reboot).

When executing `adb shell reboot` you make `adb` run shell: `/system/bin/sh` which then executes `/system/bin/reboot` binary. You can also set the system property manually:

```
~$ adb shell setprop sys.powerctl reboot,just_testing
```